# sorting many arrays according to a sorted index of an array C#

Tags: c#, sorting

```
int[] a = {120, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20};
int[] b = {12, 29, 37, 85, 63, 11};
int[] c = {30, 23, 90 ,110, 21, 34};
```

Now i want to sort a and use its index to sort b and c

For eg:

```
sorted a = {20,30,40,50,60,120};
sorted b should be ={ 11,63,85,37,29,12};
and sorted c should be = { 34,21,110,90,23,30};
```

How to do it in C#

Comment: Do you *have* to have three arrays? Typically a better approach here is to have a single array where each element is composed of the three values. That's generally cleaner as presumably the values are related to each other.

Comment: I tried to use sorting using keys and values .. like Array.Sort(a,c) and Array.Sort(a,b).. but I get unwanted results

Comment: I.e. Enumerable.Zip twice, OrderBy, than split again...

Comment: After executing `Array.Sort(a, b)`, `a` and `b` will be out of sync, and thus you will mess up the relationship.

Comment: does your all array contains the same number of element? @user2546342

Comment: Yes all array contains same number of element

Answer (score 2):

One option:

```
int[] a = {120, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20};
int[] b = {12, 29, 37, 85, 63, 11};
int[] c = {30, 23, 90 ,110, 21, 34};

var ordered = a.Select((item, index) =>
                       Tuple.Create(item, b[index], c[index]))
               .OrderBy(tuple => tuple.Item1).ToArray();

a = ordered.Select(tuple => tuple.Item1).ToArray();
b = ordered.Select(tuple => tuple.Item2).ToArray();
c = ordered.Select(tuple => tuple.Item3).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a layer of indirection, like this:

1. Put the values 0, 1, 2, ..., N-1 into an int array, named indices, say.
2. Sort the array indices such  that a[indices[i]] <= a[indices[i+1]] for all i. Your compare function will compare a[indices[Left]] with a[indices[Right]].
3. Access elements in the other arrays using the indirection: a[indices[i]] and so on.

You could make new copies of a, b and c if you wish, using the order defined by indicies. But you also have the option of not modifying the original arrays.

This option of not modifying the original arrays is quite interesting. It allows you have have multiple simultaneous orderings active in tandem.

Answer (score 0):

Got bored so I tried to minimise the creation of new objects and sorting.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] a = { 120, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20 };
    int[] b = { 12, 29, 37, 85, 63, 11 };
    int[] c = { 30, 23, 90, 110, 21, 34 };

    var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length).OrderBy(i => a[i]).ToArray();

    var temp = new int[a.Length];
    foreach (var arr in new[] { a, b, c })
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) temp[i] = arr[indexes[i]];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) arr[i] = temp[i];
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", a));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", b));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", c));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Not the best it could be (I'm sure you can get rid of the temp array somehow) - but a different solution nonetheless.  I'd support sticking with the LINQesque solutions until performance becomes an issue.

Comment: String.Join will not compute with int array. @NPSF3000

Comment: Your logic is correct but Could you please mention why Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", a)); giving me 2 compile time error.
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Error 2 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'string[]'

Comment: @Rezoan my guess is that you're using the .net 3.5 (or earlier) framework... or maybe mono?  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx for String.Join<T>

Comment: i am using version 3.5

Comment: @Rezoan String.Join<T> was added in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SortedList for this. SortedList sorts your items using a Key. Also it allows you
to add new items to your collection.

```
SortedList Class: 
Represents a collection of key/value pairs that are sorted by the keys and are accessible by key and by index.
```

[SortedList by MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use LINQ as Eli Arbel provided the answer.
But here is an other solution for those who don't know LINQ.

```
class Program
    {
        public static int get_key(int key , int [,] keylist)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= keylist.GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
            {
                if (keylist[i, 0] == key)
                    return keylist[i, 1];
            }
            return -1;
        }
       public static int[] Sort_by_index(int [] arr , int [] key , int [,] index_list)
        {
            int[] _out = new int[arr.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < key.Length; i++)
            {
                //Get key index
                int key_index = get_key(key[i], index_list);
                _out[i] = arr[key_index];

            }
            return _out;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] a = { 120, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20 };
            int[] b = { 12, 29, 37, 85, 63, 11 };
            int[] c = { 30, 23, 90, 110, 21, 34 };
            int[,] a_index = { { 120, 0 }, { 60, 1 }, { 50, 2 }, { 40, 3 }, { 30, 4 }, { 20, 5 } };
            Array.Sort(a);
            b =Sort_by_index(b, a, a_index);
            c =Sort_by_index(c, a, a_index);
            Console.WriteLine("Result A");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",a));
            Console.WriteLine("Result B");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",b));
            Console.WriteLine("Result C");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",c));
            Console.ReadKey(false);

        }
    }
```